# Why am I getting undefined when assigning the result of array.find to a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have place a breakpoint into a callback where I'm supposed to run a search into an array of objects. The array.find statement returns the element I'm expecting, but if I try to assign this result to a variable I get 'undefined'

```
let resultCallback = function(data) {
  var el = form.texts.find(text => {
    text.options.name === this.options.name;
  }, that);// breakpoint is here
//in console, form.texts.find(text => {text.options.name === this.options.name}, that); returns the element I"m looking for
// but el still is 'undefined'

};
```

I'm not sure I'm using any reserved variable names, but changing names around did not solve the issue. When looking into documentations, I see that I can assign the result of find to a variable, so I"m not sure what's going wrong here.

Could anybody help?

Comment: `.find()` returns `undefined` if the predicate matches no elements of the array.

Comment: Oh also, when you use `{ }` around the body of an `=>` function, you have to use an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: the return statement thing did the trick... I had no clue of this oversight. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with the context. the context of this object you use belongs to resultCallback function, as it's not an arrow function. I don't know where this function is declared but try to change it to arrow function first. i.e.

```
let resultCallback = (data) => {
  var el = form.texts.find(text => 
    text.options.name === this.options.name, that
  );
};
```

You're passing this object reference as second argument to find, which is unnecessary because when you call resultCallback function, you're not passing 'that' as parameter to the function. And also remove the curlies from arrow function so that it returns the result of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your find function doesn't return anything, which by default means it returns `undefined`. Either lose the code block on lines 2-4, or use return statement before `text.options.name === this.options.name;`

When using arrow functions, return keyword is required if you define a block. Otherwise it will return the expression right after arrow.